# Keep Scene resolutions in sync

Tags: interface, drivers, scene, resolution

Different Scenes can  have different resolutions. But a lot of the time, you'll always want them to be the same. Its a big hassle to have to update several other scenes all the time, especially while still working on things. And for whatever reason, you cannot use Drivers on the resolution fields.

Is there any workaround to have my secondary scenes always have the same resolution as my primary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will apply the resolution of the first scene to all other scenes. It will auto-update all scenes as soon as you change the resolution in the first scene.

```
import bpy

def set_resolution(scene):
    x = bpy.data.scenes[0].render.resolution_x
    y = bpy.data.scenes[0].render.resolution_y
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        scene.render.resolution_x = x
        scene.render.resolution_y = y

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.append(set_resolution)
```

All you have to do is run the script once after opening your project in the *Scripting* workspace.

[image: Run script in scripting workspace]

Comment: I haven't worked with the new handlers in 2.8 so if another handler would be more appropriate for this task, let me know and I'll update the script.

Comment: It looks like I have to run it every time I open the file, unless I check Register so that it auto-runs on file opening. Thanks!